# When trying to run Android Studio sh file, chmod +x and checkbox just instantly fails (as root too)

Tags: android, scripts

I want to run the new Android Studio IDE just released at Google I/O 2013, and when I try to execute studio.sh, it opens it in a text editor. If I enable running as application in properties, it instantly unchecks the checkbox. When I chmod +x it and then run it, it says permissions denied. I do the same thing as root (sudo su), and it says command not found. I use vanilla sudo for both of them. Command not found. How do I execute the file?

Comment: Note that I am not running pure Ubuntu unity, I installed GNOME 3.8 and ubuntu-gnome-desktop on top of it, but it is 13.04, so I think it's fine.

Answer (score 7):

Open the terminal and run:

```
cd android-studio/bin

./studio.sh
```

Comment: Please do not write such simplistic answers.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. Apparently Android Studio doesn't like being run off USB...

Comment: Your USB probably mounted as `noexec` and `nosuid`

Answer (score 1):

JVM must have special locate
read message #7 in
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55359

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically because you lack JDK.

This can be found by running the following command in the terminal:

```
cd /android-studio/bin
./studio.sh
```

So after you configured Java you'll be able to run it.

Answer (score 1):

with terminal, move to your android bin directory.

ie:

```
cd /usr/local/bin/android-studio/bin/
```

then use

```
sh studio.sh
```